# Excel column values change by condition

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have 3 columns in Microsoft Excel 2007. One is some ID, one is original ID and one is mix of those IDs. All columns have the same number of rows. The columns with ID have some unique ID numbers same as original ID. Every value in column ID has its pair in original ID, for example :

```
MY TABLE                               RESULT TABLE
ID    ORIGINAL ID   MIX ID             ID     ORIGINAL ID   MIX ID
B100  1             B100               1      1             1
B200  2             B100               2      2             1
B201  3             B100               3      3             1  
B202  4             B200               4      4             2  

etc...
```

but the MIX IDs have the mix values from ID  like seen above.
Now I want to change the values in ID with ORIGINAL ID... That is not a problem 1 -> 1 but I also want to change the values in MIX ID.... When I change B100 with 1, I need to change all values in MIX ID(B100) with 1 ... How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP is your friend

Do something like =VLOOKUP(MIX ID,Table with first col = ID and second Col=ORIG_ID,2)

Comment: right now I have find this solution on internet... It is almost the same as yours I have just divide everything on two excel  sheets.. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `VLOOKUP` for this. Check [Vlookup Document here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

[image]